Decomposition of TV distance
Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two joint distributions over (for simplicity, let's say discrete) random variables $X$, $Y$ such that $P(X,Y) = P_1(X)P_2(Y|X)$ and $Q(X, Y) = Q_1(X)Q_2(Y|X)$. Now construct a third distribution $M(X,Y) = P_1(X)Q_2(Y|X)$.
Is it the case that $d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P,M) \leq d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P, Q)$? I know this is the case for KL-divergence due to its nice decomposition of the joint distribution:
$$D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P || Q) = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_1 || Q_1) + \mathbb{E}[D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_2 || Q_2)]$$
Hence
$$D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P || M) = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_1 || P_1) + \mathbb{E}[D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_2 || Q_2)] \leq D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_1 || Q_1) + \mathbb{E}[D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P_2 || Q_2)] = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P || Q)$$
I was wondering whether a similar inequality also holds for the TV distance. For what it's worth, $d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P, M) = \mathbb{E}_{X\sim P_1}[d_{\mathrm{TV}}(P_2(Y|X), Q_2(Y|X))]$, but not sure it's helpful.
